# NetSuite SuiteScript - Constants And Inclusion

Tags: constants, include, netsuite, suitescript

I have a NetSuite SuiteScript file (2.0) in which I want to include a small library of utilities I've built. I can do that fine, and access the functions in the included library. But I can't access the constants I've defined in that library - I have to re-declare them in the main file.

Here's the main file:

```
define(['N/record', 'N/search', './utils.js'],
function (record, search, utils) {
    function pageInit(scriptContext) {
        isUserAdmin = isCurrentUserAdmin(contextRecord);
        
        if (isUserAdmin) {
            alert('Administrator Role ID is ' + ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE);
            // Do something for Admin users
        }
        return;
    }
    return {
        pageInit: pageInit
    };
});
```

You can see I include the file `./utils.js` in it. Here's `utils.js`:

```
    const ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE = 11;   
    
    function isCurrentUserAdmin(currentRecord) {
        return ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE == nlapiGetRole();
    }
```

That's the entire file - nothing else.

In the main file, the call to the function `isCurrentUserAdmin` works fine. It correctly tells me whether the current user is an admin. Note that I don't have to preface the call to `isCurrentUserAdmin` with `utils.` (`utils.isCurrentUserAdmin` doesn't work - it gives me the error `JS_EXCEPTION TypeError utils is undefined`). But when the code gets to the line that uses `ADMINSTRATOR_ROLE`, I get the error `JS_EXCEPTION ReferenceError ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE is not defined`. BTW, if I put the constant definition of `ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE` in the main file instead of `utils.js`, I get the same error when `utils.js` tries to use it. The only way I can get it to work is if I have the line defining the constant in *both* files.

Why does the inclusion work for the function, but not the constant? Am I including the library wrongly? I thought I'd have to use it as `utils.isCurrentUserAdmin` rather than just `isCurrentUserAdmin`, but to my surprise that's not the case, as I say above.

Answer (score 3):

If you have utils.js like below, you can use utils.ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE and utils.isCurrentUserAdmin() in your main file.

```
/** 
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 */
 
define ([],

function() {
    const ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE = 11;   
    
    function isCurrentUserAdmin() {
        // check here
    }
    
    return {
        ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE: ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE,
        isCurrentUserAdmin: isCurrentUserAdmin
    }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

define(['N/record', 'N/search', 'SuiteScripts/utils']

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure any member you need to access in another module needs to be exported in the source module using the return statement